# How is voltage gain typically achieved?

Tags: power-electronics

Excluding opamps and other IC's, how would one go about replicating a low voltage wave into a high voltage one?

Comment: Use a voltage amplifier. That is both a pedantic and a serious answer. Opamps are simply optimised collections of individual components - the hardware method used is not overly important,  - although the matching that can be achieved is of importance in some aspects. A very basic voltage amplifier can be built with one transistor and a few "glue" components. Very early 'solid state' opamps contained the equivalent of a few transistors and some 'glue'. And it 'goes on up' from there. An excellent start is to search Google IMAGES for   transistor amplifier and go from there.

Comment: Your question title is about typical methods, but in the body you exclude some typical methods. What is it you're actually looking for?

Comment: I figured the components made for voltage gain purposes must be composed of something and i don't like the "magic" aspect that they have right now, i want to know the ways behind them.

Comment: I checked out the transistor amp circuits and built one in sim. As far as i can tell they work by manipulating the resistance of the path to the transistor without including the transistor output itself, very clever! In sim they produce a very ugly reproduction of the wave but i think thats fine for something like a smps.

Comment: You can use a step up transformer.

Comment: "power supply" and "amplifier" are different cases: amplifiers can only output voltages up to (near) their voltage supply rails, but accurately reproduce the shape of the input signal. Which do you want?

Comment: As pointed out by @Andyaka a transformer is one method. Another is a transistor amplifier there are many useful circuits for this and some are described here: [The Transistor as a Voltage Amplifier](http://users.tpg.com.au/users/ldbutler/TransisVoltAmp.htm). An opamp IC will contain a similar circuit but has already been optimised for you.

Comment: @pjc50 actually a power supply and an amplifier are very similar if you think about it.  A power supply is just an amplifier where the gain is applied to the error between the actual and the desired output.

Comment: @JasonMorgan yes for linear, not really for switchmode

Comment: You can make a very simple, but non-linear and inefficient voltage amplifier with just one transistor and two resistors. (plus two capacitors for AC coupling)

Answer (score 1):

These days we mostly use amplifier integrated circuits or transistors to provide voltage gain, we used to use thermionic valves. All of these are active devices, but in the spirit of your question, there is a 'passive' solution; read on....

A transformer will give you voltage gain, but not power gain.  A transformer can only transfer less than 100% of the input power to the output.  So if you increase the voltage by useing a 1:N step up transformer you will get a corresponding reduction in output power (i.e. less current) at the output.  This is of no use in power electronics (the keyword topic of this question).

What you really want is a MAGAMP (Magnetic Amplifier), this uses a saturable transformer an AC power source and a small DC (or DC biased AC) control signal.  Now as we increase the current from the control signal it pushes the transformer into saturation, when in saturation no more AC current can pass so the output reduces.  We reduce the control signal, now the transformer moves out of saturation, the AC magnetic field increases and so does the output current.

MAGAMPs are a bit of a lost art, but do have their place, certainly in AC/DC and DC/DC converter circuits.

Voltage and power gains in the order of 10 or so are possible.  I.e. The output is 10 times the input with the same sort of current magnitude as the input.

This page on [Magnetic Amplifiers](http://sparkbangbuzz.com/mag-amp/mag-amp.htm) gives a great introduction.
There is also a good (if ancient) PDF ([here](http://teslapress.com/magamp.pdf))

Comment: I fail to see how a mag-amp can amplify a low voltage signal into a high voltage signal given your explanation. The OP talks about a low voltage "wave" that to me means an alternating signal. Your explanation talks about DC controlling an AC power waveform. Maybe you can elucidate?

Comment: A control signal would be Vctrl = Vbias + Vac, where Vac is the input 'wave' in the question. i.e. the control signal never goes negative. (Actually the control signal is a current without a sign rather than a voltage)  So a magamp only amplifies a DC input, if it's AC it needs biasing (or rectifying).

Comment: yes, the control signal would need biasing but, the output is the power AC modulated by the input signal. This is AM not amplification.

Comment: The output is both larger and more powerful than the input, that's the definition of amplification, is there another? One of the links has a good video of a 1k variable resistor (good for < 1W) dimming a car headlamp (> 100W) with nothing more than a couple cheap mains transformers and a permanent magnet if you don't believe me.

Comment: You are missing the point - the OP wants to amplify a signal rather than control power - note the word "replicating" in the question.